# personalizar input para multiupload de imagens

Tags: javascript, html, css, upload, input

Como posso personalizar um campo input do tipo file para multiupload de imagens?

gostaria de pegar algumas informações da imagem, como: formato, tamanho.

(sei que existem diversos plugins para tal, mas gostaria de aprender do zero como fazer)

Ex:

[image: Multiupload de imagens personalizado]

Comment: Cara, eu costumo fazer uma div com para estilizar e o input eu deixo com `display:none`, aí em Jquery eu faço o clique da div ser no input.

Comment: Talvez se estudar o código fonte destes plugins, ajude também.

Comment: Recentemente estou usando o [jQuery FileUpload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload). Ele é bem complexo, então pode ser que você tenha um certo trabalho em implementar algo exatamente nesse estilo, com tamanho do arquivo, ação de cancelar e etc.

Answer (score 2):

Existem limitações de que tipo de informação está acessível no JavaScript. Do lado do servidor é diferente e pode obter-se mais informação. Mas ainda assim alguns parâmetros estão acessíveis.

Exemplo:

```js
$('#ficheiros').on('change', function () {
    var label = $(this).prev();
    var tamanho = this.files[0].size;
    var nome = this.files[0].name;
    var tipo = nome.split('.').pop();
    var info = 'Nome do fichiero: ' + nome + ', Tipo de extensão: ' + tipo + ', tamanho em bytes: ' + tamanho
    label.html(info);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="ficheiros"></label>
<input id="ficheiros" type="file" />
```

### Tamanho do ficheiro

Acessível via `this.files[0].size`. Para converter em Kb pode usar esta função [que encontrei](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18650828/2256325):

```
function bytesToSize(bytes) {
   var sizes = ['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB'];
   if (bytes == 0) return '0 Byte';
   var i = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(1024)));
   return Math.round(bytes / Math.pow(1024, i), 2) + ' ' + sizes[i];
};
```

### Nome do ficheiro

Acessível via `this.files[0].name;`

### Extensão do ficheiro

Tendo o nome do ficheiro pode fazer `nome.split('.').pop()` para obter só a extensão.